# Assign variables value to a variable

Tags: addition, variable-assignment, tcsh, integer-arithmetic

Using the command line, I've defined two variables

```
set a = 5
set b = 5
```

In addition I've set another variable, `c`, in which I am trying to assign `a`'s and `b`'s value.

I tried -

```
set c = $($a+$b)
```

But I've got `Illegal variable name.`

I tried -

```
set c
c = $($a+$b)
```

But I've got `Illegal variable name.`, again.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `set`? Where did you get the `$($a+$b)` syntax? None of this looks like bash code.

Comment: The following might help: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html

Comment: Please show outout of `echo $0`.

Comment: the output is /bin/tcsh

Comment: @AlexGoft Why are you asking about `bash` if you're actually using `tcsh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set variable and assign value:

  ```
  @ a = 5
  ```

  This is same as:

  ```
  set a = 5
  ```
- See value of the variable:

  ```
  echo $a
  ```

> You may try following way:

```
    @ a = 4
    @ b = 5
    @ c = $a + $b

    echo $c
    9
```

**Don't forget @, it's used instead of 'set'**

[You can have some basic ideas about working in tcsh from this site](http://www-cs.canisius.edu/ONLINESTUFF/UNIX/shellprogramming.html)

PS. Never worked in `tcsh`so please take my answer/suggestion with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to:

```
a=5
b=4

c=$(($a + $b))
# test
echo $c
# prints 9
```

Note that double parenthesis and the removal of the [`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) keyword.

Comment: But if im trying to write in command line `a=5`, i get `a=5: Command not found.`. That's why i used set.

Comment: @AlexGoft Set doesn't do what you think. Also, maybe you had a space between the left and the right sides of the "=", which shouldn't be there.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Turns out the question is actually about tcsh, not bash.

Comment: @melpomene I think in this case it should be posted as a new question, since this one already has an answer and was tagged bash for a while.

Answer (score 1):

```
set a = 5
set b = 5
set c = `expr $a + $b`
```